# Django select field with thousands of choices creating thousands of database queries

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models, model B and model C, which both extend model A.

In a form I have a model select field for model A - this obviously loads all instances of model B and C which was my intention.

So this dropdown is over 1000 'A Objects'. I am using hasattr() to determine if they're B or C, which then uses the **unicode** method from those classes to display the object in string from in the dropdown.

This creates thousands of SQL queries which takes around a minute to process. Right now my solution is to query the database 3 times (to get all A, B and C objects, and then loop over A and decide if each oject is of type B or C and push the correct unicode string into a list which is used in the dropdown. I then clean the data and select the right object when saving the form. This is hackey (to me).

I was wondering if anyone knows of an efficient way of populating a dropdown with thousands of model object choices when that model is a Base Model for other models.

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: What exactly do the unicode methods do? they shouldn't cause extra queries

Comment: Objects of B or C have a foreign key field to other models. - unicode gets a field from these other models (self.foreign_key_field.field_to_print_out). So for example, a single object is type B (extends A), and I want to print out a field from Model X which best represents this object (and is related via foreign key). Would select_related() come into play here? (ps. I'm new to Django)

Comment: That is correct, I've rewritten my answer (since the original was written on a long saturday night and completely incorrect...) to hopefully explain where the 1k queries come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> unicode gets a field from these other models (self.foreign_key_field.field_to_print_out).

This is where the other queries are made, not from the call to unicode or checking if its a b or a c.

Had your unicode method reference only local fields this wouldn't have been an issue, but as you have noticed fields that require a join are not done automatically to save some performance on things that may not even be required.

If you use django-debug-toolbar, you should notice that the 1000 queries are the retrieval of the related object, not the list of a objects.

So yes, as you've pointed out, `select_related` would help here since this is you telling django that you do require these fields.

Comment: The 1k+ items are necessary unfortunately. Users need to have access to a nationwide collection of values. I'm using a django library for select2 to manage the UI perspective of this. Could you explain how .annotate is working here? I can't figure it out (I dont have much experience with complex queries)

Comment: Wont this still hit the DB once for each object though? That would still be upwards of a thousand queries to the database...

Comment: Again I'm not fully too sure of how annotation works... but as far as I can tell  if my_queryset was 'A.objects.all()', all this annotation would do would provide a way of seeing if it's of type b or c. How would I get all objects of type A and their _unicode__ representations in a single query?

Comment: Got this working by using select_related('tablename', 'tablename__foreignkey'). Double underscore to delve deeper into the relations and prevent thousands of queries.

Comment: @DeanSherwin - Interesting, does just `select_related('foreign_key')` not work? I'm not sure if i've misunderstood your usage correctly and think I read somewhere about select_related doing more about params for fields that don't exist. Either way glad it worked and sorry about the foobar answer before!